# Redirecting standard output stream

Tags: file-io, prolog, prolog-toplevel

How do I write the output of `listing/0` in SWI-Prolog REPL to a file ?

```
?- listing > file.txt.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can open a file for writing and redirect `current_ouput` to it like this:

```
?- current_output(Orig), % save current output
   open('file.txt', write, Out),
   set_output(Out),
   listing,
   close(Out),
   set_output(Orig). % restore current output
```

Alternatively, SWI-Prolog provides a predicate [`with_output_to/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=with_output_to/2) which can be used to redirect the current output for one goal. Make sure to read the documentation, but in short:

```
?- open('file.txt', write, Out),
   with_output_to(Out, listing),
   close(Out).
```

Now the output of `listing/0` will be written to `file.txt`.
But keep in mind that there is going to be a whole lot of stuff in there. You maybe want to use `listing/1` for specific predicates? In this case, using [`clause/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/2) and [`portray_clause/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=portray_clause/2) is another option, especially if you want more control over what and how you are writing to the file. `listing` is meant only for interactive use I guess.

Comment: Why do you say that `portray_clause/2` is preferred, when `listing(specific_pred/1)` would just do what is desired? With `portray_clause` much more has to be handled manually.

Comment: @false Just because of that same reason I guess. I always felt that `listing/1` is meant for using at the top level (this is how I use it at least). If one starts writing to a file, I just assume they are doing more sophisticated things than taking a look at a predicate's definition. I will correct my wording.